# How can I bind an id to an ajax request url in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have url for the page as https://test.com/deaileditem.php?id=5

I need to take this id and attach at the end of my ajax request to get the json data.

I took this using the code

```
var id = window.location.href.split('=').pop()
             console.log(id)
```

My vue js code is

```
<script>
still = new Vue({
    el: '#cat',
    data: {
        les: [],
    },


    mounted() {
        var m = this;
         var id = window.location.href.split('=').pop()
             console.log(id)
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://text.com/post/get/id",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",

            success: function(e) {
                 m.les = e;
                console.log(e.les)

            },
        });
    },


})
</script>
```

Instead of 'id' in the url ( url: "https://text.com/post/get/id"). I need to attach the id I obtained so that new url is ( url: "https://text.com/post/get/5").  How can I able to give the obtained id to get the required json data. I am very basic in js. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't appended the `id` in `url`

Change

`url: "https://text.com/post/get/id",`

to

`url: "https://text.com/post/get/" + id,`

Comment: It should work (better - there of course could be other errors)

Comment: @med you can mark this as an answer if this helped :)

Comment: sure.. I try to mark.. but it says.. wait for 2 minutes.. Thanks a lot sir.. For your help.. Sir.. Can I ask you a doubt also.. Is there any other way to pass that id from the previous page to this page?

Comment: @med if want to use javascript only, you'll have to read the `GET` parameter and create the new url. Otherwise you can also handle it on the server-side. You can get the `id` in php itself, create the url, and pass it to the frontend ( and use it in ajax )

Comment: Is there any problem if I do in this way

Comment: Try var id = document.referrer.split('=').pop()

Comment: shouldn't be a problem I guess. but if you already know the value, it's better to send it from server

Comment: ohkkie.. tanku sir